# What is this plane

Tags: plane, tool-identification

I bought this plane 35 years ago at a flea market just because I liked it.

[image]

[image]

Can any one tell me what it is or is it a combination of parts?

Comment: Nearly two weeks now, abandoned Q? I can't see if the OP has been back since a recent change (?) to the user page seems to no longer show last visit, for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: It's not a plane, it's Superman! _shows self to the door..._

Comment: Abandoned questions seem all too common here, @Graphus. :(

Comment: I'm enjoying that our answers are _basically_ the same, but one shows a North American bias, and the other a UK bias.

Comment: @FreeMan, yes. What are we running, around 7/10? :-(

Comment: @jdv, er, no. I didn't want to come right out and say so before (I was letting my Answer do the talking) but this is in no way a transitional. Infills of this style came out of a planemaking tradition that predated metallic planes by about 100 years!

Comment: @Graphus huh. The internet seems to have agreed that a transitional plane has a wooden body with metal parts. I just looked this up in something called a "book" from decades ago. But I misunderstood the line drawings within, and I assume the author intended to show the sole as all wood. I'd always assumed they were roughly the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is built in the style of a **British infill plane**, with an iron or steel body, hardwood 'stuffing' (mahogany?) and brass or bronze lever cap.

It's a smoothing plane, or as commonly called today a smoother, which are intended to be the last plane in a sequence that takes wood from rough to perfectly flat and flawlessly smooth.

We can just make out in the first photo that it has a Norris iron (and presumably cap iron) fitted, but that doesn't mean it is a Norris as both parts were sold as separate components. While superficially it looks like one of their planes that weren't fitted with the now-famous-again Norris adjuster I don't believe Norrises ever had such prominent screws through the cheeks holding the infills in place. This and other key details I think argue strongly against this being a Norris.

So despite how professionally made this looks there is a chance it's a user-made tool; possibly from a kit of parts sold through a magazine.

More on infill planes, if you're interested, at [The Infill Planes Showcase](http://www.infill-planes.com/).